# What is the different between `add target` and `implements a delegate` in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

For example, I make a `MyUIElement`, I can accept the user click it. When the user click it, the user can define a method for me when I click it. For example, they can increase the count by 1, when I click it.

So, if I am thinking on how to implement this logic...I can make a `MyUIElementDelegate`, and call back the `MyUIElementDelegate`' s `onMyUIElementIsClicked:` function, or I can allow user to `addTarget: action: forEvents:`. These two ways also works. But what is the different between them? Thanks.

Comment: Easy: Controls prefer Selectors > Delegates.  Selectors are cheap, and easily invoked when your object recieved a certain event.  Delegates require callbacks, which can be optionally or mandatorily implemented, but that binds a control to one set of selectors implemented by the object that owns the delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the method to be called is on the same class, **addTarget** would be easier but if the method is defined in another class, **implementing delegate** would be a better idea to invoke the method. With a little bit of extra coding, delegate protocol will give you more flexibility, by the fact that it has two types of methods: @required and @optional.